# Android- How to handle application's multiple instances

Tags: android

What the way to manage multiple instances of Android application? I want to close the ruuning application's instance when user launch the same application from Application menu.

Regards,
Android_IT

Comment: mode="singleTop" attribute or something ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to clear the backstack and start from the beginning if that is what you're looking for

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```